# How to configure TeamCity to perform clean build without deleting NuGet packages?

Tags: svn, teamcity, nuget

I am using TeamCity for my CI builds.  To keep things simple suppose there are only two build steps:

1. NuGet Installer -> Creates the packages folder and download from NuGet.org
2. Visual Studio (sln) -> Build code

Before these run I would like the entire working directory to be reverted to match the SVN repo; deleting the bin/obj/anything else that might have snuck in.
Only new changes in SVN should be downloaded, not the entire repo.

However, the packages folder should not be cleaned, because downloading these takes too long.

How could can I do this?

Some things I have tried:

- "Clean build" checkbox on the "Version Control Settings" page, however this will delete the entire working directory.
- "Revert before update" checkbox on the "Edit VCS Root" page.  This does not affect the bin folder, perhaps because it is not tracked by SVN.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't check the box "Clean all files before build:" on the VCS settings page, VCS by default downloads only the updates from SVN. Now regrading bin/obj folders, you could add a step to clean the solution before any other step. Cleaning the solution will delete bin/obj contents.